# pd.to_datetime() returning incorrect date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I'm trying to extract all of the unique values in a date column. In this case, there is only one value so it's easy to see the error.

The code I'm using to see this is:

```
print df['Date'].unique()
print pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d").unique())
```

The two results I'm getting are

```
['2016-06-01']
```

for the first line and

```
['2016-05-31T20:00:00.000000000-0400']
```

for the second line. Is there a way to correct this?

**Edit:**

For EdChum's comment.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

archive = pd.read_csv(r'J:\xxxx\xxxx\Archive.csv')
date_list = archive['Date'].unique()
date_list_test = pd.to_datetime(archive['Date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d").unique()

print date_list
print date_list_test
```

[image]

Comment: can you post raw data and code to reproduce the above, it seems like somehow your timezone is introducing an offset which is odd

Comment: Hey @EdChum I posted the code in the question. For the raw data, do you me to just type out what it looks like? I don't think I'm able to upload the actual csv on here

Comment: Can you post enough lines of your csv that reproduces the error though?

Comment: @EdChum I posted an image that shows the df.head() and the outputs for the 2 lines of code.

Comment: I think this is your environment's timezone interfering, what is the dtype that you want eventually here? `str` or `datetime`?

Comment: does `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=True)` work or `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).tz_localize('utc')`?

Comment: neither solution worked sadly

Answer (score 1):

This is just an issue with how `numpy` is displaying the dates - in version `1.11` it goes away.

```
In [55]: np.__version__
Out[55]: '1.10.4'

In [56]: pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-31'])
Out[56]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [57]: pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-31']).values
Out[57]: array(['2015-05-30T19:00:00.000000000-0500'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In [58]: pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-31']).values)
Out[58]: 
0   2015-05-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

numpy 1.11

```
In [94]: np.__version__
Out[94]: '1.11.0'

In [96]: pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-31'])
Out[96]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [97]: pd.to_datetime(['2015-05-31']).values
Out[97]: array(['2015-05-31T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Hey @chrisb will this correct the incorrect date? I'm not just looking at a formatting change. The pd.to_datetime() is returning 5/31/16 instead of 6/1/16 for some reason

Comment: This should just be a display issue - see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6453) for more information.  Try wrapping your results (which are a plain `numpy` array) back in a `Series` and it should show the correct date?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I'm trying to install numpy and am getting weird error. I have to install manually because of company intranet. When I run the setup.py I'm getting SystemError: One of the required function to build numpy is not available (The list is ['sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'sinh', 'cosh', and a bunch more

Comment: To be clear - you don't need to update your numpy.  This is only a *display* issue - the values are correct.  I've updated my answer with an example that may make this clearer.